# Basic question regarding Taylor's theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Consider $f$ near $x=0$.

If there is a degree $\leq n$ polynomial $p(x)$ such that $f(x) = p(x) + O(x^{n+1})$, does this imply $f$ is $n$ times differentiable at $x=0$?

This is (roughly) the converse of Taylor's theorem.

My opinion, without proof: Yes, since $f$ behaves 'locally' like the polynomial, it should be $n$ times differentiable. However, I haven't made any progress in a proof. I haven't thought of a counterexample either.

Comment: $\mathcal O(h)$ only makes sense if yous specify as $x\to a$.  For example, consider a non-differentiable function that is $\in\mathcal O(x^{n+1})$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It's clear in this context that we want $x \to 0$. Note how I said 'near $x=0$'. Pretty standard omission (especially in computer science! But there it's usually taken for granted that $n \to \infty$)

Comment: Ah, I missed that part.  =P  But again, we can have non-differentiable function $\in\mathcal O(x^{n+1})$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: Good question. +1

Comment: A good starting point: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88501/converse-of-taylors-theorem

Comment: Another simple counterexample: $$x^{n+1}\sin\left(\frac1{x^{n+1}}\right)\in\mathcal O(x^{n+1})$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result appears to be obviously / intuitively true, but one should never trust intuition in dealing with real analysis. All I could prove using this assumption is that $f(0) = p(0), f'(0) = p'(0)$. It appears that it is not possible to prove that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$. This is only to be expected because derivative at a point is a local phenomena and the equation $$f(x) = p(x) + O(x^{n + 1})$$ says only about the behavior of $f$ near $0$. It does not say anything about behavior of $f$ near any other point $a \neq 0$. <strike>While I am not able to construct a counter-example to disprove this, I find myself equally unable to prove the claim. I suspect the claim is false.</strike>

An easy counter-example is $f(x) = x^{n+1}$ for rational $x$ and $f(x) = x^{n+2}$ for irrational $x$. Then $f(x) =O(x^{n+1})$ as $x\to 0$ and $f'(0)=0$ yet $f'$ does not exist in neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: And a good answer to the good question.+1

Comment: $x^n\sin(1/x^n)$ is a good enough counter-example.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. And it's a continuous counter-example.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: yes that is a very good counter-example in the sense that $f'$ exists in a neighborhood of $0$ but it is not continuous at $0$ so that $f''(0)$ does not exist and in general higher derivatives of all order exist everywhere except $0$. So weird behavior near $0$ and yet it is $O(x^{n}) $ as $x\to 0$.